# How to mark the checkbox in repeater in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, radio-button, repeater

I am using checkbox control under repeater to do a radio button functionality, everything seems to be fine but now stuck on how to bind the checkbox when the page loads. I have saved the radio button text whichever was selected and once user come back to page again I want to bin what he has selected last time. Not getting any hint here how to proceed.

```xml
<grial:Repeater
    x:Name="PP"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    InitialSelection="Empty"     
    ItemSize="100"
    HorizontalOptions="Start"
    ItemsSource="{Binding BlowerPostions}">
    <grial:Repeater.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <grial:Checkbox
                IsChecked="false"
                UncheckedBorderColor="Black">
                <Label
                    TextColor="Black"
                    Text="{ Binding . }"
                    Margin="8,0" />
            </grial:Checkbox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </grial:Repeater.ItemTemplate>
    <grial:Repeater.SelectedItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <grial:Checkbox
                IsChecked="true"
                UncheckedBorderColor="Black"
                InputTransparent="true">
                <Label
                    TextColor="Black"
                    Text="{ Binding . }"
                    Margin="8,0" />
            </grial:Checkbox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </grial:Repeater.SelectedItemTemplate>
</grial:Repeater>
```

View Model :

```
public class ProductionViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<BlowerPostion> _blowerPostions;

    public ObservableCollection<BlowerPostion> BlowerPostions
    {
        get => _blowerPostions;
        set
        {
            _blowerPostions = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new 
                PropertyChangedEventArgs("BlowerPostions"));
            }
        }
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
      BlowerPostions = new ObservableCollection<BlowerPostion>();
      BlowerPostions.Add(new BlowerPostion("Left", 1));
      BlowerPostions.Add(new BlowerPostion("Standard", 1));
    }
}

public class BlowerPostion
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public BlowerPostion(string _text, int _id)
    {
        Text = _text;
        Id = _id;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to bind `IsChecked` to a property of your model, not hardcode the value

Comment: How to bind which checkbox will be true or false? do you have any example. I have tried to bind it already but it didnt work

Comment: You need a ViewModel.  Right now your ItemsSource is just a hardcoded list of strings

Comment: I already have a ViewModel, Should I create a object of these strings and put as itemsource?

Comment: you need a model that represents whatever data you want to display in the Repeater

Comment: that's fine but again how I will checked the checkbox when user comes back after saving the option first time?

Comment: you bind the UI to your model, then save the model and reload it when you want to display the UI again

Comment: @Jason I have edited my question with view model, now can you guide me how to select the selectedItem when user loads page again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235763/discussion-between-zeeshan-shaikh-and-jason).

Comment: you need bool values to model checkboxes.  And its very unclear why you need TWO checkboxes to model a single bool condition, instead of a single Checkbox or Switch or RadioButton.

Comment: I have shared image on chat, I am trying to achieve a radio button using checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use `grial:Repeater`,but you can refer to the following code which use `CheckBox` in `ListView` item.

**Item.cs**

```
public  class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    //This field indicates whether or not it is selected
    public bool isChecked { get; set; }
}
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
public  class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> items { get; private set; }

    public MyViewModel() {
        items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        items.Add(new Item { Name = "Tomato", Type = "Fruit", Image = "tomato.png", isChecked = true });
        items.Add(new Item { Name = "Romaine Lettuce", Type = "Vegetable", Image = "lettuce.png", isChecked = false });
        items.Add(new Item { Name = "Zucchini", Type = "Vegetable", Image = "zucchini.png", isChecked = false });
    }
}
```

TestPage1.xaml

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="listview" ItemsSource="{Binding items}"         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5,0,5,0">
                        <Label  Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="30"/>

                        <input:CheckBox    IsChecked="{Binding isChecked}"  Type="Check" Color="White" BoxBackgroundColor="Green" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="40" 
                                         CheckChanged="CheckBox_CheckChanged"  BindingContext="{Binding .}" />

                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

TestPage1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class TestPage1 : ContentPage
{
    public List<Item> selectedItems; // define `selectedItems` as the list of selected items.

    public MyViewModel viewModel;

    public TestPage1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        selectedItems = new List<Item>(); // init the `selectedItems`
        viewModel = new MyViewModel();

        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void CheckBox_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var checkbox = (Plugin.InputKit.Shared.Controls.CheckBox)sender;
        var ob = checkbox.BindingContext as Item;

        if (ob != null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("isChecked = " + ob.isChecked  + "<--->  Name = " + ob.Name +"<--->  Type = " + ob.Type );
            if (ob.isChecked)
            {
                selectedItems.Add(ob);
            }
            else {
                // remove the item
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note:

1.add new field `isChecked` in item model

```
 public bool isChecked { get; set; }
```

2.Add event `CheckChanged` for the item.And when we check the CheckBox,we can get the corresponding value `isChecked` of the `CheckBox`.

```
<input:CheckBox    IsChecked="{Binding isChecked}"  Type="Check" Color="White" BoxBackgroundColor="Green" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="40" 
                                         CheckChanged="CheckBox_CheckChanged"  BindingContext="{Binding .}" />
```